# newbie need help ! !

Tags: iphone, plist, badge

ok guys so i'm new in iphone dev you know it !

I want to add badge from my app : i know how to in the application did finish launching.

But i want to it depending on an int value i have stored in a plist (just one string an int value) i have placed on my server htt://anadress/myplist.plist

How can i read the content of this value in the plist from my server thanks to all it'll help so much

Comment: Someone should probably edit his question and title for him.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [arrayWithContentsOfURL](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/arrayWithContentsOfURL:) method or the corresponding NSDictionary, NSString, etc methods.

Comment: thnaks a lot so i have to create an array using arrayWithcontentOfURL

Comment: Just to be clear, it doesn't *have* to be an array, that's just one example of how to load data from a URL. There are similar methods for whatever data structure you are using in your plist.

And if this is the correct answer, you can mark it by clicking the checkmark.